# More trivia than really important: Why no new() constraint on Activator.CreateInstance<T>()?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, c#-2.0, base-class-library

I think there are people who may be able to answer this, this is a question out of curiosity:

The generic `CreateInstance` method from `System.Activator`, introduced in .NET v2 has no type constraints on the generic argument but does require a default constructor on the activated type, otherwise a `MissingMethodException` is thrown. To me it seems obvious that this method should have a type constraint like

```
Activator.CreateInstance<T>() where T : new() {
   ...
}
```

Just an omission or some anecdote lurking here?

**Update**

As pointed out, the compiler does not allow you to write

```
private T Create<T>() where T : struct, new()
error CS0451: The 'new()' constraint cannot be used with the 'struct' constraint
```

However, see comments a struct can be used as type argument to a generic method specifying a new() constraint. Under this circumstance the given answer seems the only valid reason to not constrain the method...

Thanks for looking over this!

Comment: +1 Very interesting question. I can't think of a reason why it shouldn't be there, so I'm curious to find out why, too!

Comment: As to your update, because it's redundant; all value types have a default constructor that initializes all values to defaults (it's what you get when you call `default(T)`.

Comment: All structs have default ctors in C#.

Comment: Just to clarify, given `void Foo<T>() where T:new() {}`, `Foo<DateTime>();` or `Foo<int>();` are both perfectly valid calls that the compiler won't complain about.

Comment: Excellent question. I am baffled. The `new` constraint appears to have been introduced at the same time as generics, so it's not like it's a backwards-compatibility issue. Maybe they just forgot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could be wrong, but the main benefit as I see it is that it allows you to do something like this:

```
// Simple illustration only, not claiming this is awesome code!
class Cache<T>
{
    private T _instance;

    public T Get()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = Create();
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    protected virtual T Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Note that if `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` had a `where T : new()` constraint, then the `Cache<T>` class above would *also* need that constraint, which would be overly restrictive since `Create` is a virtual method and some derived class might want to use a different means of instantiation, such as calling a type's internal constructor or using a static builder method.

Comment: +1. That's an excellent point. While you're assuming some risk (it's possible that `T` doesn't have a default constructor here, obviously), this seems like a perfectly valid case.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable` does this very thing.

Comment: Also worth noting that a `CreateInstance<T>` method constrained with `where T : new()` would be completely redundant. Since `T` must be known at compile-time, then any `T` constrained with `where T : new()` can be created using `var x = new T()` syntax.

Comment: @LukeH: Ha, yes, it's kind of funny to think that this is the question being asked, whereas if `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` *did* have the `where T : new()` constraint, there would most assuredly be an SO question, "What the heck is the point of `Activator.CreateInstance<T>`?"

Comment: @Dan, LukeH: For what it's worth, calls to `new T()` are, in fact, turned into calls to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.

Comment: @Adam: That's true for ref-types, but as far as I'm aware `new T()` will always compile to an `initobj` instruction for value-types. (I'm not sure why `new T()` can't be compiled down to a `newobj` instruction for ref-types rather than a call to `CreateInstance<T>`.)

Comment: @Adam: If I declare a method `T M<T>() where T : new() { return new T(); }` then the value-type path is special-cased using `initobj`, compiling down to something roughly equivalent to `if (default(T) != null) return default(T); return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();`